# Ко/х/ти, но но/к/ти в старомосковском говоре

Tags: орфоэпия

Ушаков в [видео](https://youtu.be/VWQZwV0Xy10?t=1111) говорит об этом. Не могу понять, почему возникает такая разница.

Answer (score 2):

**Вместо вступления**

Почему не отвечают? Тема орфоэпии интересна не всем — ведь для практического письма нам бывает достаточно тех знаний, которые мы получили еще в начальной школе. Но вот в теме произношения звуков Г, К, Х  желательно **дополнительно знать** классификацию согласных по месту и способу образования.

**Фонетическая справка**

Звуки Г, К, Х по месту образования относятся к группе **заднеязычных,** а по способу образования мы различаем **смычные** (взрывные)  Г, К (парные звуки, звонкий и глухой) и **фрикативный** глухой Х.

**Что это значит**?  При произношении смычных согласных кончик языка прижат к нёбу, и струя воздуха разрывает эту смычку. Остается только включить голосовые связки для звонкого Г.

При произношении **фрикативного** Х между кончиком языка и нёбом образуется щель, через которую с шумом  проходит воздушная струя. Фрикативные звуки могут тянуться, в отличие от смычных (мгновенных) звуков.

**О чем рассказывается у Ушакова**

1. Как известно, звонкие согласные на конце слова **оглушаются**,  поэтому вместо Г мы произносим К:  ***вдру(к), со всех но(к)***.

Но вот в слове ***бо(х)*** мы оглушаем Г до фрикативного Х, а почему? Ушаков не дает объяснений, так что приходится искать причину самим.  В данном случае мы не произносим К, так как в языке есть слово ***бок***, и мы не должны их произносить одинаково.

2. Также мы говорим:  ***ле(х)кий*** (оглушение перед глухим К), а здесь-то в чем дело? Здесь согласный Г будет стоять перед  К, и тогда мы получили  **удвоение** КК.
3. А как мы произносим ***ногти*** и ***когти***? Это тоже интересно: в старомосковской речи произношение было такое: ***ко(х)ти*** и ***но(к)ти***. Может быть, не нравилось близкое соседство двух звуков К?

**А сейчас?** *Ну-ка, кошка, убери ко(к)ти*. Вроде бы мы говорим К или что-то среднее между ними. Да, действительно, вот и в орфоэпическом словаре указано, что ***ко(к)ти***. И написано: произношение ***ко(х)ти*** устарело. Но там и про ***ногти*** то же самое написано. Вероятно, оба варианта встречались в речи, да и сейчас могут так сказать.

**Вроде бы разобрались.** Фрикативный звук Х используется только в отдельных словах, и этот факт можно как-то объяснить.

**P.S.** А вот южнорусское произношение характерно тем, что там произносится фрикативный звук Г перед гласным, когда в сильной позиции согласные не меняются, например: «Ты ш(о) там  (г)оворишь?». И вот этого звука в нормированной речи  **вообще нет**.

Comment: Спасибо большое! И всё-таки, почему, по-вашему, Ушаков говорит, что в "ногтях" не Х? Не очень это понял всё равно.

Comment: Ушаков всего лишь излагает ФАКТЫ, то есть какое произношение считалось НОРМОЙ в старомосковской речи, и это всё. А в ненормированной речи, вероятно, встречались оба варианта, судя по словарю. ПОЧЕМУ ТАК? Ушаков ничего не объясняет, поэтому думать приходится самим на уровне ГИПОТЕЗ.  Возможно, точная информация где-то есть, но разве найдешь! Если только случайно попадется. Это, пожалуй, все, что я пока могу вам сказать.